# Linux/unix sleep command: How do I check the time remaining for queued processes in a task manager such as 'top'?

Tags: linux, unix, process, queue, sleep

The command:

```
sleep 3600 && ls
```

will run the command 'ls' after 3600 seconds. But when I run the task manager using the command 'top', such queued processes of course don't show up. How do I find out what processes are queued and how much time is remaining before they'll run ?

Comment: To whoever voted this question down, I would appreciate if you could leave a comment when you do that, so that I can learn how to improve my questions. In my mind this question was clear, without being unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 2):

`ps aux|grep sleep` will give you a list of instances of "sleep", their durations, and when they were started.  I'm not aware of any way to see what process will be run when the "sleep" command expires.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how it works though since I've never come across ps or aux before. I'm also not sure what you mean in the last sentence. Thanks very much for providing me with the solution though!

Comment: @user1271772 - read manual of `ps` command. ps shows info about currently active processes running in foreground or background in your system and as sleep is a running process in your system it will show you that info.